# Can't Add and Remove Div to Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I cant get this code to work. It's supposed to be a custom dialog box. When a certain event transpires, the div pops up with an animation like it's moving towards you from a distance. The div has a clickable link that is supposed to trigger the removal of the box when clicked.

It works fine for one iteration, but when I attempt to trigger it again the whole thing falls apart in a horrendous way. The console doesn't issue any warnings or errors, but the browser freezes then crashes.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function modalBoxOpen(left, top, width, height, string, element){

var x = $('<div></div>').prependTo(element);

x.attr("id", "pop_up_div");

x.css("position", "absolute");

x.css("border-color", "black");

x.css("border-style", "solid");

x.css("background-color", "rgb(204, 204, 204)" );

x.css("padding", 0 + "%");

x.css("z-index", 10);

var y = $('<div>' + string + '</div>').prependTo(x);

y.attr("id", "inner_pop_up_div");

y.css("text-align", "center");

y.css("font-family", "arial");

y.css("position", "absolute");

y.css("margin", "1%");

y.css("width", "98%");

y.css("height", "93%"); y.css("background-color", "red");

var l = left + .5*width; 

var t = top + .5*height;

x.css("left", l + "px");

x.css("top", t + "px");

x.css("width", 2*(left + .5*width - l) + "px"); 

x.css("height", 2*(top + .5*height - t) + "px");

y.css("font-size", .0413*2*(left + .5*width - l) + "px");

$('<div style = "background-color: black; border-radius: 10px; padding                    

:   1%; margin-top: 1%; margin-left: 43%; margin-right: 43%">' +

'<a class = "link" id = "ok_button" href = "javascript:;"> OK </a>

</div>').appendTo(y);



okButtonClick = function(e){ 

  e.stopPropagation();     

  removeElement('pop_up_div');

  $(".input_cover").css("display", "none");

  bindHandlers();

  if ( $("#language_list_container").is(":visible") )

  {$("#language_clickable").click();}

  }

  $("#ok_button").bind("click", okButtonClick);


  var count = 0;

  timer = setInterval(open, 40);

  function open(){

  if ( count > 4 ) { 

     clearInterval(timer);

     bindHandlers();

     return;

   }

   l -= .1*width;

   t -= .1*height;

   x.css("left", l + "px");

   x.css("top", t + "px");

   x.css("width", 2*(left + .5*width - l) + "px"); 

   x.css("height", 2*(top + .5*height - t) + "px");

   x.css("border-radius", 2*(count+1) + "px");

   y.css("font-size", .0413*2*(left + .5*width - l) + "px");

   count++;

   }

   }

   function removeElement(id) {
   return          

   (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
   }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: `return`          ???? why is this a first statement. following code wont get executed

Comment: that stops the animation.

Comment: The animation works fine. it's just when i try to retrigger the whole thing more than once it fails.

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: never used it before. i'm still new.

Comment: Here's one: http://jsfiddle.net/bx2qk0co/

Comment: @Tribute I don't think the `return` is a problem -- it's just badly formatted. It's actually returning a value, but it's 2 lines down.

Comment: how did you fix my code? where was my mistake?

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin It definitely returns `undefined`. [Automatic semicolon insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) will insert a semicolon immediately after `return` in this case.

Comment: i was paranoid about the animation. so i returned just to make sure it stops.

Comment: @Teemu You're right, I just assumed extra line breaks appeared -- there are a lot of them.

Comment: @tensor I didn't really do much, just a small amount of formatting.

Comment: then where is my problem? must be with the function that makes the initial call.

Comment: sorry about the formatting. only been coding a few weeks. dont really know whats acceptable.

Comment: @tensor As well as legibility, it can have functional consequences, as pointed out above with javascript's automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: so the code i posted works when isolated?

Comment: @tensor Try replacing your script with the code in the fiddle and see if it works.

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir You should answer this, I think your answer is correct.

Comment: same problem. but at least i know where not to look now.

Comment: the calling function is a part of an ajax call. might that be pertinent?